# Failure to establish SSL connection from CLIENT to PROXY with LoadRunner

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, loadrunner

Using HP loadrunner I'm trying to connect to a server with chrome browser.

Chrome throws this after some time:

```
ERR_SSL_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY
```

I see this in the LR log:

```
...
[Network Analyzer (1344: 654)]   (Sid:  3) Negotiate Proxy -> Server SSL Handshake (ssl:TLSv1.1, ciphers:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA)
[Network Analyzer (1344: 8f0)] Address lookup for Mindaugas-LenW7 = 10.0.2.15 [Network Analyzer (1344: 8f0)] Request Connection: Remote Server @ 55.7.5.99:443   (Service=)  (Sid=  8)  PROXIED!
[Net An. Error    (1344: 654)]   (Sid:  3) Negotiate Client -> Proxy SSL Handshake Failed!!!
...
```

If I understand correctly L.R. intercepts the chrome (client) requests, so there are two SSL sessions established:

```
Chrome --> L.R.
L.R. --> Server
```

The first one fails.

Here are the things I have tried.:

- Downloaded the certificate and added to L.R.
- Provided a specific port mapping :443.

Here is what I'm seeing - a successful handshake(L.R to server, so same as before)
[image]

And here is my port mapping:
[image]

Also, just when the recording starts and finishes I'm being offered to delete a certificate - not sure why, would be grateful for an explanation:

[image]

**QUESTION: what else should I do to be able to record via chrome?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a defect in Loadrunner and a hotfix has been released.

This is the hotfix included in this KB:

https://softwaresupport.hp.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM01860986?lang=en&cc=us&hpappid=202392_OSP_PRO_HPE

Note that a HP login is required to view the above link.

Comment: Apparently you have to be a paying user to get the hotfix ... not sure if that is the correct policy for a company that is just considering L.R. an want to check the free version. 

What would be your suggestion? Should I wait for another version? Revert to the old one?

Comment: From what I can gather you can just register for free and then still download it? Sometimes HP allows it sometimes they don't. Otherwise from what I can gather this problem affects older versions of Loadrunner too.

Comment: I was not able to download it after registration